# accessing of Directory in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

good evening guys, i  am using google colab, because it supports GPU and TPU   and without it, i can't run  many Deep Learning codes on my computer, i have installed already google colab ,just question is following:
let us suppose my working directory is this
https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1EvNegzEhMp0NtKXY_Hm9jsBpA4Amwcs

here i can upload images, csv files and so on, i have searched a lot of  material about this one  and i found  following

```
from google.colab import drive
 drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

i have run this code and follow instructions and  finally i got : Mounted at /content/drive

after that i  have uploaded simple file to this directory and run following code

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2
import skimage
from skimage import data
from skimage import io
Image =cv2.imread('palm.jpg')
io.imshow(Image)
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dtype' , i have searched documentation about this error and found, that  my Image might be [] , so what is reason of  an error? please help me

Comment: Did you check in which directory you are currently running these commands?

Comment: Full directory is : MyDrive/Machine Learning/OpenCV

Comment: Check image extensin .jpg or .jpeg

Answer (score 2):

Mention full path of image in code **'/content/drive/MyDrive/Machine Learning/OpenCV/palm.jpg'**

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2
import skimage
from skimage import data
from skimage import io
Image =cv2.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/Machine Learning/OpenCV/palm.jpg')
io.imshow(Image)
```

Comment: If this is not working Check image extension .jpg or .jpeg

Answer (score 0):

When you mount your drive, look for the "drive" folder in your contents. You have to find the path to the image from that folder. It may be something like `img_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/sample.jpg'`.

Comment: i have image in this  folder

Comment: Do you see that folder in your drive under contents?

Comment: If you do see it, you can replace `Image =cv2.imread('palm.jpg')` with `Image =cv2.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/Machine Learning/OpenCV/palm.jpg')`.